# LLVM IR optimization

Tags: llvm, compiler-optimization, llvm-ir, register-allocation

I am trying to follow [this](http://laure.gonnord.org/pro/research/ER03_2015/lab1_intro.pdf) link in order to generate an IR representation for a `c` code. The `c` code that I am using is as follows

```
void main() {
 int c1 = 17;
 int c2 = 25;
 int c3 = c1 + c2;
 printf("Value = %d\n", c3);
}
```

Which I save it as `const.c`. Once it is saved, I use the following command in order to generate a `.bc` file.

```
clang -c -emit-llvm const.c -o const.bc
```

Once the .bc file is generated, I want to use the following command in order to generate the optimized version of the `const.bc` file which is named `const.reg.bc`.

```
opt -mem2reg const.bc > const.reg.bc
```

I don't have any issues generating these files but for some reason both of them are exactly the same and no optimization happens. The results should be different, I mean `const.reg.bc` should be an optimized version of the `const.bc` file. But for some reason it does not happen. Can someone tell me what is it that I am not doing right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `clang somefile.c`, it defaults to -O0 optimization level, which emits main function with `optnone` attribute. This attribute prevents optimizations, which is why you don't see the result of `mem2reg`.

You have to remove `optnone` attribute if you want `opt` to do work:

```
clang -S -emit-llvm const.c -o - | sed s/optnone// | opt -S -mem2reg
```

Note thet `mem2reg` and its counterpart `reg2mem` passes are not strictly optimizing. They are just converting the IR from/to SSA form.

Comment: Thanks @arrowd . However in the following, on page 17, they optimize it with the same commands that I put up here. Why is the discrepancy between my optimizer and theirs? When I output the textual IR, mine is different than theirs. The optimized version and non-optimized version of my IR is basically the same. While for them it's different. What I mean is that in their textual IR, optimization actually happens.
http://laure.gonnord.org/pro/research/ER03_2015/lab1_intro.pdf

Comment: Ah, I get it. `clang` defaults to `-O0` optimization level, which emits `main` function with `optnone` attribute. Edit `const.ll` file in the text editor and remove `optnone` keyword from `attributes #0` enumeration. After that, `mem2reg` gets applied successfully.

Comment: Thanks @arrowd. Is there a way to avoid this without having to go through the file and removing the keyword? Also, please edit you response above so that I can mark it as solved.

Comment: You can use `sed` for that.

Answer (score 9):

This option can be used with clang `-Xclang -disable-O0-optnone` to prevent generation of `optnone` attribute.